# *Perfect* vertical image alignment

Tags: css, alignment

I have a square div of fixed size and wish to place an arbitrary size image inside so that it is centred both horizontally and vertically, using CSS. Horizontally is easy:

```
.container { text-align: center }
```

For the vertical, the common solution is:

```
.container {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But this is **not perfect**, depending on the font size, the image will be around 2-4px too far down.

To my understanding, this is because the "middle" used for vertical-align is not really the middle, but a particular position on the font that is close to the middle. A (slightly hacky) workaround would be:

```
container {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

and this works in Chrome and IE7, but not IE8. We are hoping to make all font lines the same point, in the middle, but it seems to be hit-and-miss depending on the browser and, probably, the font used.

The only solution I can think of is to hack the line-height, making it slightly shorter, to make the image appear in the right location, but it seems extremely fragile. Is there a better solution?

See a demo of all three solutions here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/usvrj/3/

Those without IE8 may find this screenshot useful:

[image: IE8 screenshot when font-size is set to 0]

Comment: +1 just for asking a well written question with a very neat demo!

Comment: I achieved something similar by using jQuery and calculating the margins on page load. Not pretty, but it worked in IE6+ & Co.

Comment: Have you tried adding `display: table-cell;` to the container?  It is my understanding that the vertical-align property can have two different meanings, one for table cell content, and one for inline elements.

Comment: `display: table-cell` looks to be the same, example 4 at http://jsfiddle.net/usvrj/6/

Comment: What about the table itself? It also has this problems?

Comment: font-size: 0; saved my day, who knew?? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using your image as a background? This way you could center it consistently everywhere. Something along these lines:

```
margin:5px;
padding:0;
background:url(http://dummyimage.com/50) no-repeat center center red;
height:60px;
width:60px;
```

Comment: This isn't an exact solution to the problem, but it seems to be the only way to get a perfect position, so I'll accept it. It's either this, or accept a small line-height hack in the CSS.

Answer (score 3):

If css3 is an option, then flexbox does a good job at vertical and horizontal aligning:

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/usvrj/9/)**

```
.container {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is REALLY hacky, but it is what we used to do in the ie6 days.

```
.container {
     position: relative;
}
img {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     margin-top: -12px; // half of whatever the image's height is, assuming 24px
     margin-left: -12px; // half of whatever the image's width is, assuming 24px
}
```

I may be missing something in this example, but you get the idea.

Comment: This is a great way to center things, not a IE6 hack. But this solution doesn't works for him since the image size is arbitrary, so there is no way to calculate the margins.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
img {
    display: block;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

I usually use this hack, but I haven't really checked it that thoroughly in IE8.

Comment: Can you give an example of it working in any browser? Vertical align doesn't work with `display: block`, so I'm not seeing how this would work.

Comment: You're right, you would also need a display: table-cell on the parent container. Maybe try just the line-height: 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small JS Fiddle I have made: http://jsfiddle.net/rachit5/Ge4YH/

I believe it matches your requirement.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src=""/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{height:400px;width:400px;position:relative;border:1px solid #000;}
img{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;}
```